# Can a basis have smaller cardinality than weight of the topology?

Tags: general-topology

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Weight_and_character) Wikipedia page there is following property

> if $B$ a basis of $X$ then there is a basis $B' \subseteq B$ of size $|B'| \leq w(X)$.

where $X$ is a topological space and $w(X)$ is a weight of said topology.
But, since weight of a topology is a minimum cardinality of all the bases, wouldn't it be better to simply write that the size of $B'$ is equal to $w(x)$, because it can't be smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem with that section is that the weight of $X$ is not actually the minimum cardinality of a base for the topology: it’s customary to require it to be infinite, so if $\kappa$ is the minimum cardinality of a base for $X$, we define

$$w(X)=\max\{\omega,\kappa\}=\omega+\kappa\;.\tag{1}$$

If $\kappa$ is finite, it really is possible to have a base for $X$ whose cardinality is less than $w(X)$.

It appears to me that the statement that you quoted was based on $(1)$ instead of the definition of weight given at the beginning of the section.